# Pandas hierarchical data from read_csv

Tags: pandas

I got a csv data file containing this kind of data :

```
value0,value1.1,value1.2,value2.1,value2.2
```

I'd like to get to this kind of structure :

```
 data0   data1             data2
         sub1     sub2     sub1     sub2
value0 value1.1 value1.2 value2.1 value2.2
```

so that I can access data with `mydata['data0']` and `mydata['data1']['sub1']`.

I understand I should use pandas.MultiIndex, but I can't get my head around this.

The header names ("data1", "sub1",...) would be stored in the script.
I'd like to NOT duplicate header names because I have 60 columns of data…

Until now, this was performed with Numpy by simply using a hierarchical np.dtype with np.loadtxt.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(<csv_file>, header=None, index_col=0)
column_names = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('data1', 'sub1'),
                                          ('data1', 'sub2'),
                                          ('data2', 'sub1'),
                                          ('data2', 'sub2'),
                                          ('data2', 'sub3')],
                                          names=['level0', 'level1'])
df.columns = column_names
```

For following file:

```
1,'aa', 'ab','ba','bb','bc'
2,'ac','aa','bd','ba','bc'
```

```
df.head()
```

```
Output:

level0  data1   data2
level1  sub1    sub2    sub1    sub2    sub3
0                   
1   'aa'    'ab'    'ba'    'bb'    'bc'
2   'ac'    'aa'    'bd'    'ba'    'bc'
```

```
df['data1']['sub1']

Output:
0
1    'aa'
2    'ac'
Name: sub1, dtype: object
```

```
df['data2']
```

```
Output:
level1  sub1    sub2    sub3
0           
1   'ba'    'bb'    'bc'
2   'bd'    'ba'    'bc'
```

gives following:

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it on monday. That's not as perfect as it could be because data1 and data2 are repeated in the tuples, but it could be generated. Also, is it possible to have one column with only one level ? (like the data0 in my example)

Comment: Well, all columns must have same no. of levels in multiindex. So, for single column still need to make a level ("data0", "sub0"), it is little extra code, but would make things much cleaner.